# How to revoke a token Apereo CAS Oauth

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I am using Apereo CAS with supports OAuth2.0 ([Link to docs](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html)). I am successfully issuing the access token through path:

```
[url_cas]/oauth2.0/accessToken?grant_type=password&client_id=[client_id]&username=[user]&password=[password]
```

How to revoke this access token generated (Application logout)? I didn't find in the documentation any information.

I tried to execute logout with Apereo CAS Rest ([Link to docs](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html)) through path:

```
DELETE [url_cas]/v1/tickets/AT-1-g6G2c3PwFrsXoSYlVhrrdLCqjiUQgkMS
```

And Apereo CAS returns a error:

```
Ticket [AT-1-g6G2c3PwFrsXoSYlVhrrdLCqjiUQgkMS is of type class org.apereo.cas.ticket.accesstoken.AccessTokenImpl when we were expecting interface org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicket
```

Is there any way to perform this operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that capability is available in CAS 5.2.x. It may be possible to see the active sessions using the `/status/ssosessions` endpoint (once you turn it on and enable secure access to it). Alternatively, you could create your own endpoint to do this securely.

See [this link](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Monitoring-Statistics.html).

Starting with CAS 6.1, there is a dedicated endpoint available for OAUTH tokens, `/actuator/oauthTokens`, that is modeled as a Spring Boot actuator endpoint. It allows you to manage and control OAuth2 access tokens:

- A GET operation produces a list of all access/refresh tokens.
- A DELETE operation will delete the provided access/refresh token provided in form of a parameter selector. (i.e. /{token}).
- A GET operation produces with a parameter selector of /{token} will list the details of the fetched access/refresh token.

See [this link](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html#administrative-endpoints) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe that it will be better to create a own endpoint for this operation because otherwhise it would hava to allow users to access the CAS monitoring endpoints.